# Groups of RadioButtons

Tags: wpf, xaml

```
<RadioButton Content="1" GroupName="a" IsChecked="{Binding a, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=RadioButton}, ConverterParameter=1}" />
<RadioButton Content="2" GroupName="a" IsChecked="{Binding a, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=RadioButton}, ConverterParameter=2}" />
<RadioButton Content="3" GroupName="a" IsChecked="{Binding a, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=RadioButton}, ConverterParameter=3}" />
<RadioButton Content="1" GroupName="b" IsChecked="{Binding b, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=RadioButton}, ConverterParameter=1}" />
<RadioButton Content="2" GroupName="b" IsChecked="{Binding b, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=RadioButton}, ConverterParameter=2}" />
<RadioButton Content="3" GroupName="b" IsChecked="{Binding b, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=RadioButton}, ConverterParameter=3}" />
```

I have two groups of RBs, and three RBs in each groups. Each group have equal values of RBs.

2 questions:

1. How can I get disabled RB in group if I have clicked on RB with value like in it in other group? Is it possible to develop it in XAML without C# code?
2. How can I do in XAML, that the RB was clicked in each group by default? IsChecked used by Binding, and I cann't do IsChecked="true". Now I do it in ViewModel, but i think it can do in XAML.

Sorry for mistakes, if any, and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer the first question..

You can do that in Xaml, it's too complicated, and even if it is possible it won't be readable...

I know Xaml.cs is not a good place for code, but this is a pure ui code so I prefer write it in the Xaml.cs and not in the ViewModel

And about the second question, the MVVM way is to set it in the ViewModel
[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3247858/2830676), that's not exactly your question but I understand your answer from there

Comment: 1. Ok i see. I want ask you if you're saying what it not possible how would you decide this task? i'm beginner in C# and XAML. 2. Yes, I set this value at initialization ViewModel. But I'm asking would it possible to do with XAML methods only?

Comment: 1. As I said, use the "code behind" (.xaml.cs extension). 2. I believe not, it's also a bad practice in my opinion

Comment: You have 3 parts: 1. xaml - for pure view, 2. code behind - for complicated pure view, 3. ViewModel - for managing the logic of the view with the model (hope I defined it correctly)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Converter for inverting boolean value. And this is meaning C#, because i think there is no boolean invert converter in xaml.

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(bool))]
public class InvertBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (targetType != typeof(bool)) throw new InvalidOperationException("Value must be boolean");
        return !((bool)value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

You can use define this converter in XAML like this,

```
<Window.Resources>
        <local:InvertBooleanConverter x:Key="rbc"></local:InvertBooleanConverter>
</Window.Resources>
```

And in some StackPanel or Grid you can use InvertBooleanConverter for RadioButton

```
    <RadioButton x:Name="rb1a" Content="1" GroupName="a" IsChecked="True" IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=rb1b, Converter={StaticResource rbc}}" />
    <RadioButton x:Name="rb2a" Content="2" GroupName="a" IsChecked="False" IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=rb2b, Converter={StaticResource rbc}}" />
    <RadioButton x:Name="rb3a" Content="3" GroupName="a" IsChecked="False" IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=rb3b, Converter={StaticResource rbc}}" />
    <RadioButton x:Name="rb1b" Content="1" GroupName="b" IsChecked="False" IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=rb1a, Converter={StaticResource rbc}}" />
    <RadioButton x:Name="rb2b" Content="2" GroupName="b" IsChecked="True" IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=rb2a, Converter={StaticResource rbc}}" />
    <RadioButton x:Name="rb3b" Content="3" GroupName="b" IsChecked="False" IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=rb3a, Converter={StaticResource rbc}}" />
```

Comment: I didn't think about it. Thanks. But it is answer at first question. In this code I'm losing the bind with InClincked in my ViewModel. I see that in second question is hard to use XAML in my task. Only C# code in ViewModel. Perhaps, have to sacrifice the second question.